# Checking for (and Deleting) Complex Object Duplicates in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

So I need to duplicate check a complex object, and then cascade delete dupes from all associated tables and I'm wondering if I can do it efficiently in SQL Server, or if I should go about it in my code. Structurally I have the following tables.

- Claim
- ClaimCaseSubTypes (mapping table for many to many relationship)
- ClaimDiagnosticCodes (ditto)
- ClaimTreatmentCodes (ditto)

Basically a Claim is only a duplicate if it is matching on 8 fields in itself AND has the same relationships in all the mapping tables.

For Example, the following records would be indicated as duplicates

```
Claim
Id     CreateDate    Other Fields
1      1/1/2015      matched
2      6/1/2015      matched

ClaimCaseSubTypes
ClaimId    SubTypeId
1          34
1          64
2          34
2          64

ClaimDiagnosticCodes
ClaimId    DiagnosticCodeId
1          1
2          1


ClaimTreatmentCodes
ClaimId    TreatmentCodeId
1          5
1          6
2          6
2          5
```

And in this case I would want to keep 1 and delete 2 from the Claim table as well as any rows in the mapping tables with ClaimId of 2

Comment: You have an interesting problem, but no question.  What are  you trying to do?  Get all duplicates?  Get duplicates of a single case?  Delete duplicate cases from the database?  Just have a query return non-duplicated cases?

Comment: Thank you for the comment Gordon. I have edited the question. I want to delete duplicates, leaving only the earliest created record

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the kind of problem that window functions are for:

```
;WITH cte AS (
    SELECT      c.ID,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY field1, field2, field3, ... ORDER BY c.CreateDate) As ClaimOrder
    FROM        Claim       c
    INNER JOIN  other tables...
)

UPDATE Claim
    SET         IsDuplicate = IIF(cte.ClaimOrder = 1, 0, 1)
    FROM        Claim c
    INNER JOIN  cte ON c.ID = cte.ID
```

The fields that you include in the `PARTITION BY` indicates what fields need to be identical for two claims to be considered matched. The `ORDER BY` tell SQL Server assign the earliest claim the order of 1. Everything that doesn't have the order of 1 is a duplicate of something else.

Comment: I wasn't aware that you could PARTITION BY on multiple tables. This is such a clean, simple solution that I'm sorry I didn't think of it. Thanks!